# How to create database use servlet?

Tags: database, jsp

I want to create tables in jsp when user run the jsp file first time,like we install wordpress,it can create table by itself.Can it use the sql file?

PS:just because my friend ask me to make a jsp website,in his computer of course,,but he know nothing about mysql,so I think I should let the program create database,like we install wordpress,we just enter username and password ,it can create everything for us.

Comment: yes , it can, but I am curious why to create tables by jsp , is that a good practice?

Comment: JSPs are view components, intended to generate markup. They should not contain business logic. They should not even contain Java code. Use a servlet, and learn how to execute queries using JDBC. Google for JDBC tutorial.

Comment: thank you,I know to use JDBC,I just wonder how to use JDBC to call sql file.

Answer (score 0):

This class will execute a script from a file:  http://pastebin.com/f10584951

Use something like this inside a JSP page.

```
ScriptRunner scriptRunner = new ScripRunner(connection);
Reader reader = new FileReader("path to file");
scriptRunner.runScript(reader);
connection.commit();
```